# Suppress SplitViewController for iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape, iphone-6-plus

I am creating an universal app. It looks good for all iPhones and iPad models except for the iPhone 6(s) plus. In landscape mode the iPhone 6 plus behaves like an iPad with a split screen. I would like to suppress this behavior and want the same behavior for the iPhone 6 plus as for all other iPhone models.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding some logic in your code to change your app depending on the model type and orientation:

```
var device = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
var orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
```

Hope this helps

Comment: UIDevice.currentDevice().model only returns "iPhone" and not the exact model.